# Netbeans JPA+EJB with Oracle doesn't work

Tags: oracle, jsf, jpa, netbeans, ejb

I've done a exhausting research trying to fix my proyect and I haven't found an answer
I have JDK 1.7 I'm using netbeans 7.3 with Glassfish 3.3.1 and Oracle Database 10g Express Edition my idea is to create a web project with jpa, ejb and jsf.
I was able to connect netbeans to the oracle database using ojdbc6.jar driver, to create the persistance first I created a resource, connection pool, then I added the persistance.xml unit, after that I used the assistant to create the entity classes from database and finally the session beans from entity classes, then I add the framework of jsf with primefaces to the project, I add the faces-config and I create a managed bean to that point everything works just fine, so here's the problem, when I want to use the Facade to consult the database with the method findAll() it rolls back the transaction, which is really weird is that if I right-click the persistance unit and run a JPQL statement it works fine but when I want to get the resultset in a List it doesn't work...
Here's the bean:

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package controller;

import ejb.EmployeesFacadeLocal;
import entities.Employees;
import java.util.List;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.ejb.EJB;

/**
 *
 * @author Miguel
 */
public class beanInicio {
    @EJB
    private EmployeesFacadeLocal employeesFacade;
    private Employees em;
    private List<Employees> lstEm;

    @PostConstruct
    public void inicializar()
    {
        this.em = new Employees();
        this.lstEm = this.employeesFacade.findAll();
    }

    public beanInicio() {
    }

    public Employees getEm() {
        return em;
    }

    public void setEm(Employees em) {
        this.em = em;
    }

    public List<Employees> getLstEm() {
        return lstEm;
    }

    public void setLstEm(List<Employees> lstEm) {
        this.lstEm = lstEm;
    }

    public EmployeesFacadeLocal getEmployeesFacade() {
        return employeesFacade;
    }

    public void setEmployeesFacade(EmployeesFacadeLocal employeesFacade) {
        this.employeesFacade = employeesFacade;
    }
}
```

Has anyone come across with this kind of problem? How did you solved it?

Comment: post all the relevant code and the stack trace

Comment: Thanks for replying, I don't know what the problem is for some strange reason it is working now, and I didn't do anything, maybe the Oracle  listener wasn't working sorry for troubling you :S